# CSS does not apply to printed document

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to print a document:

```
function print(html) {
        $('<iframe>', {
            name: 'myiframe',
            class: 'printFrame'
        }).appendTo('body').contents().find('body').append(html);

        window.frames['myiframe'].focus();
        window.frames['myiframe'].print();
        setTimeout(() => { $(".printFrame").remove(); }, 1000);
}

var html = '<head>' +
               '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css" type="text/css" media="print">' +
               '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/vahan.css" type="text/css" media="print">' +
               '</head>' +
               '<body>' +
               '<div>Test</div>' +
               '</body>';
print(html);
```

The problem is that I see pure html without any of css applied. There's definitely something simple that I can't figure out. Any hints?

Comment: You need to place the `html` in the document before you append the iframe to the body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first append the html to the document before you can add the iframe.

```
function print(html) {
  // Add the html
  document.innerHTML = html

  // Append the iframe to the body
  $('<iframe>', {
    name: 'myiframe',
    class: 'printFrame'
  }).appendTo('body').contents();

  window.frames['myiframe'].focus();
  window.frames['myiframe'].print();
  setTimeout(() = > {
    $(".printFrame").remove();
  }, 1000);
}
```